# Using dependency injection in .NET 7.0 API controller project with inheritance and explicit call to base class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, dependency-injection

This is for a learning project. How can I inject an `IHttpContextAccessor` or any class into the base service class without injecting it into the derived classes when the derived classes make a call to base(argument) in their constructors?

I am trying to avoid having to add the dependency to all derived classes in their constructors because they will not use it. I have a base service class:

```
type namespace MagicVilla_Web.Services
{
    public class BaseService : IBaseService
    {
        public IHttpClientFactory httpClient { get; set; }
        public APIResponse responseModel { get; set; }

       ** public IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;** //  <== I want to inject this in this class

        public BaseService(IHttpClientFactory httpClient)
        {
            this.responseModel = new();
            this.httpClient = httpClient;         
        }

        public async Task<T> SendAsync<T>(APIRequest apiRequest)
        {
           // do a bunch of stuff
        }
}
```

and derived classes which inherit from the BaseService class but explicitly call the BaseService in their constructors.  The common business logic for the SendAsync<T> function is in the BaseService class which is why I want the IHttpContextAccessor injected into the BaseService class.

Whenever I inject and call these derived service classes, they call the baseService constructor with 1 argument and I cant seem to find a way to get dependency injection to work

```
namespace MagicVilla_Web.Services
{
    public class AuthService : BaseService, IAuthService
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
        private string villaUrl;

        public AuthService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, IConfiguration configuration)  : base(clientFactory)
        {
            _clientFactory = clientFactory;
            villaUrl = configuration.GetValue<string>("ServiceUrls:VillaAPI");
        }

        public Task<T> RegisterAsync<T>(RegistrationRequestDTO obj)
        {
            return SendAsync<T>(new APIRequest()
            {
             //call base class SendAsync with arguments
            });
        }
```

Another service class which inherits from BaseService

```
namespace MagicVilla_Web.Services
{
    public class VillaService : BaseService, IVillaService 
    {

        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
        private string villaUrl;

        public VillaService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, IConfiguration configuration) : base(clientFactory)
        {
            _clientFactory = clientFactory;
            villaUrl = configuration.GetValue<string>("ServiceUrls:VillaAPI");
            
        }

        public Task<T> CreateAsync<T>(VillaCreateDTO dto)
        {
            return SendAsync<T>(new APIRequest()
            {
     //call base class SendAsync with arguments
            });

        }
```

I tried adding multiple constructors to the base class, but this does not work because the base class is never directly invoked, its methods are only called through the derived classes so the 2 argument constructor does not work.

```
type namespace MagicVilla_Web.Services
{
    public class BaseService : IBaseService
    {

        public IHttpClientFactory httpClient { get; set; }
        public APIResponse responseModel { get; set; }
        public IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

public BaseService(IHttpClientFactory httpClient,IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor ) // <== does not work
        {
            this.responseModel = new();
            this.httpClient = httpClient;  
            this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public BaseService(IHttpClientFactory httpClient)
        {
            this.responseModel = new();
            this.httpClient = httpClient;         
        }


}
```

If I add the injected class into all of the derived constructors and their calls to the base class, then injection does work, but this seems difficult to maintain.

```
AuthService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)  : base(clientFactory, httpContextAccessor)

VillaService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(clientFactory, httpContextAccessor)
```

Everything should be set correctly in my Program.cs.  I am not injecting the BaseService class anywhere.

````
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IVillaService, VillaService>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IVillaNumberService, VillaNumberService>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
         
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();```
````

Is there some way to inject the IHttpContextAccessor into the BaseService class without having to alter the constructors of the derived classes?

I looked at the documentation and didn't see anything that particularly referenced this use case.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-usage

Comment: You can't, you need to inject it into the derived class

Comment: This is where composition over inheritance comes into play. If the derived classes are "not using the dependency" then why are they inheriting from the base class to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I add the injected class into all of the derived constructors and their calls to the base class, then injection does work, but this seems difficult to maintain.

Indeed, that's how inheritance works in C# (and all other languages I know well enough to compare it to). If a base class *depends* on something, that dependency doesn't vanish when another class inherits from it.

So either you supply the dependency by chaining it, as shown in the OP, *or* you hard-code a particular instance into your derived class (usually not recommended).

Is this difficult to maintain?

Yes, it is.

What's the solution?

> Favor object composition over class inheritance.
>
> - [Design Patterns](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/dp)

Don't use inheritance as a vehicle of code reuse. Instead, *inject* the services you need, and only when you need them.

In case the above isn't clear enough: *Don't use inheritance at all*. Throw away the `BaseService` class, and instead supply services that implement behaviour like `SendAsync`. The classes that need that behaviour can have that service injected into their constructors, and the classes that don't just ignore it.

I've been programming in C# since 2002-ish and haven't used inheritance for more than a decade. You can easily do without it. Things will be easier that way.